# Were there any elements of socialism in Nazism?

Tags: germany, socialism, nazism

I know that the Nazis hated communism but it is a bit ironic that they themselves had the word socialism in their party's name (National Socialist German Workers' Party. Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei in German).

My question is that is there any evidence of any socialist elements in Nazi policies or agendas?

If not then why did the Nazi party have the word socialism in its very name?

Comment: There was in fact [a socialist wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strasserism) within the Nazis, though they were purged pretty early.

Comment: As well as rejecting communism, the Nazis also rejected what they saw as bourgeois capitalism (and its semitic associations), though they were hand in glove with various powerful industrialists. It at least purported to be a "peoples movement" hence *Volkswagen* - people's car. But the questiion you raise is a very good one, on which a considered essay might be written. It is difficult to answer in a few words. It was socialism within a racial context, whereas Marxist socialism was conceived as internationalist. Naziism certainly rejects the internationalism of socialism.

Comment: @JamesK Yes. There is a very good answer provided to that question to which the OP should refer.

Comment: @JamesK Yes there is a good answer provided at that question. Perhaps the word *Volkisch* rather than *socialist* applies. And that notion was not not at all new to German history.

Comment: The Nazis added socialism to their name to win votes.  It was completely a ruse and nothing else.  Fascism and socialism have nothing in common.  In fact, countless socialists and communists were killed by the Nazis b/c of their beliefs.

Comment: Sure, every mixed econ will have aspects of the spectrum. Hitler encouraged home gardening, provided food subsidies to the needy, established universal child care and elder care, and instituted many pro-worker policies around pay and time-off. He was also a vegetarian and a rabid anti-smoking campaigner. That said, as a reprehensible figure, many will try to deny or exaggerate his socialist aspects. History is messy.

Comment: @Semaphore: Röhm's faction too, to some extent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beefsteak_Nazi#Ernst_R%C3%B6hm_and_the_Sturmabteilung